# AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I get the error message in the title when I start this script. How could I solve it? `Python 3.7`
I haven't updated any modules, it worked perfectly. Now, this error comes out.
`AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'message'`

Here is the code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GxqmMkiZ)

```
def post(bot, update):
    print(url)
    url = update.message.text.replace("/g ","")
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    nameele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5   ZIAjV ']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using depercated syntax for handler callbacks. Since v12.0, the signature of handler callbacks reads `def callback(update: telegram.Update, context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):`. Please see the [v12 transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0) for details.